# Blank slide generated between the title and the first content slides when using beamer with pandoc

Tags: beamer, pandoc

I am new to `beamer`.  Given the following *mwe*:

```
---
title: Tensorflow
subtitle: Cloud Computing Capstone Presentation 
fonttheme: structurebold
author: Stephen Boesch
fontsize: 12pt
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: no        
---

## TensorFlow!

Distributed DataFlow Graph based Mathematical Computations
Google's Second Generation Deep and Machine Learning Platform
```

And running with:

> pandoc    --slide-level=2 -H beamer.tex -s -t beamer --toc-depth=5 --toc  --pdf-engine xelatex -o mwe.pdf mwe.md

There is a blank page generated after the `pandoc` generated title slide and before the `Tensforflow!` headed first content slide.

[image]

Any tips how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: This is caused by `--toc`: The empty page contains the toc, which is empty since you are not having any toplevel (i.e. `#`) entries

Comment: nice catch.  care to make that an answer?

Comment: Well, I made an answer out of it

Comment: and you got yourself an  `(upvote,accept)` tuple ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The empty slide contains the ToC, which is empty, since you are not using toplevel devisions (i.e. `#`). This could be solved by either adding a toplevel devision:

```
---
title: Tensorflow
subtitle: Cloud Computing Capstone Presentation 
fonttheme: structurebold
author: Stephen Boesch
fontsize: 12pt
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: no        
---

# Part 1

## TensorFlow!

Distributed DataFlow Graph based Mathematical Computations
Google's Second Generation Deep and Machine Learning Platform
```

Or by omitting the option `--toc` when calling pandoc.

Answer (score 3):

@DG' has found the culprit:

> This is caused by `--toc`

He is invited to create the real/accepted answer.  In the meantime here is the (correct) result using

```
 pandoc --slide-level=2 -H beamer.tex -s -t beamer  --pdf-engine xelatex -o mwe.pdf mwe.md
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it is important to note that this will **also** occur if there is a (Markdown) comment *before* the first frame, even if `--toc` is omitted, e.g.:

```yaml
---
title: Tensorflow
subtitle: Cloud Computing Capstone Presentation
fonttheme: structurebold
author: Stephen Boesch
fontsize: 12pt
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: no
---

<!--Comment that will cause an empty frame to insert-->

## TensorFlow!

Distributed DataFlow Graph based Mathematical Computations
Google's Second Generation Deep and Machine Learning Platform

<!--Comment that will NOT cause an empty frame to insert-->
```

If comments appear after the first frame, they will not cause an empty frame to be inserted.

Comment: Keep those anecdotes coming!

Comment: Thanks to @Arthur's answer above, I realized that I had two commented lines at the end of my metadata yaml file, which were causing two blank pages to be created in the final pdf. Removing these lines also removed the blank pages! Hopefully, this experience might be helpful for someone else.